# Android Studio Structure tool

Tags: android, structure

I cant find info on this anywhere. I am wondering about the significance of Structure tool in Android Studio. It shows me the class structure with all the methods. Is it showing me *in what order* the methods will get called when the code runs or are they sorted in some other way?

Is there a way to see in what order the methods will get called apart from setting breakpoints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the icons on the toolbar, you'll know what it does. It **does not** sort in the order of it being called.

- The first icon sorts it according to the visibility of the methods,
  i.e. public, protected and then private.
- The second one sorts it by name.
- Rest of them are what contents of the file you want to show, i.e show
  variables, anonymous inner classes, etc
- It also gives you the option to expand and collapse methods and scroll to, from source.

It's basically a tool to help developers understand the structure of the file. It gives an overview of the methods at a glance for easy readablility.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Structure tool order

```
InnerClass -> Interface -> Method -> Field
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **sequence diagrams**. The Android Studio does not provide such tool, but there are external ones (e.g. [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/seqrev.jsp)) that can generate sequence diagrams from Java code, so you can see the execution order of methods.

By the way, the ordering you see in the *Structure* panel can order the fields / methods in multiple ways (you can even combine them):

- **by visibility**: this is the leftmost icon with the down arrow next to the green and red locks; it sorts the items by their visibility in the following order: public first, then protected, package private, and private
- **alphabetically**: the second icon from the left with the down arrow next to an *a* and *z* characters
- **default**: shows the items in the same order as they appear in your class

Worth mentioning that methods appear *before* fields no matter what.

*Note that what you're doing is reverse engineering, which is usually bad practice. A proper way would be that you first plan your class (and application) using class and sequence diagrams among others, then implement the solution.*